# Running linux make from wine using Programmers Notepad

Tags: wine

I've got Programmers notepad running in Wine. I would now like to configure one of it's tool capabilities for it to run linux' make. I've tried the ways of calling linux commands outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29632463/3154111 to no avail. I remember getting this to work once, but have no idea how, and that computer is now toast. I've even tried creating a bat script to run the start command for make, to no result. What other commands and methods could I try?

Comment: Should "I would not like to configure" really read "I would like to configure"? If so, I think you should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1309377/edit) the question.

Comment: @FriendFX dang, good eye.. was supposed to be a "would now" :D Fixed, thanks!